# Using environment properties with files in elastic beanstalk config files

Tags: configuration, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Working with Elastic Beanstalk `.config` files is kinda... interesting. I'm trying to  use environment properties with the `files:` configuration option in an Elastc Beanstalk `.config` file. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
files:
    "/etc/passwd-s3fs" :
        mode: "000640"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
```

To create an `/etc/passwd-s3fs` file with content something like:

```
ABAC73E92DEEWEDS3FG4E:aiDSuhr8eg4fHHGEMes44zdkIJD0wkmd
```

I.e. use the environment properties defined in the AWS Console (`Elastic Beanstalk/Configuration/Software Configuration/Environment Properties`) to initialize system configuration files and such.

I've found that it is possible to use environment properties in `container-command:`s, like so:

```
container_commands:
    000-create-file:
        command: echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${AWS_SECRET_KEY} > /etc/passwd-s3fs
```

However, doing so will require me to manually set owner, group, file permissions etc. It's also much more of a hassle when dealing with larger configuration files than the `Files:` configuration option...

Anyone got any tips on this?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  The answers below were helpful, but not sure they answered the issue of being able to use the environment variables for the file copy.   From what I have seen, the env variables are only available for the container_commands,

Comment: Unfortunately not. The below suggestions give good options for workarounds, but this still seems like an area of potential improvement for EB .config files...

Comment: I ended up using a PowerShell script.  In the commands_container, I execute a PS script that then downloads the files from the S3 based on environment variables.  Suppose it could work with other files besides ones from S3.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this.  I will use the word "context" for dev vs. qa.

Create one file per context:

**dev-envvars**

```
export MYAPP_IP_ADDR=111.222.0.1
export MYAPP_BUCKET=dev
```

**qa-envvars**

```
export MYAPP_IP_ADDR=111.222.1.1
export MYAPP_BUCKET=qa
```

Upload those files to a private S3 folder, S3://myapp/config.

In IAM, add a policy to the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role role that allows reading S3://myapp/config.

Add the following file to your .ebextensions directory:

**envvars.config**

```
files:
  "/opt/myapp_envvars" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    # change the source when you need a different context
    #source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myapp/dev-envvars
    source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myapp/qa-envvars

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: myapp

commands:
  # commands executes after files per 
  # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
  10-load-env-vars:
    command: . /opt/myapp_envvars
```

Per the [AWS Developer's Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands), commands "run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted," and before container-commands. I guess the question will be whether that is early enough in the boot process to make the environment variables available when you need them. I actually wound up writing an init.d script to start and stop things in my EC2 instance. I used the technique above to deploy the script.

Credit for the “Resources” section that allows downloading from secured S3 goes to the May 7, 2014 post that Joshua@AWS made to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=541634).

Answer (score 3):

I am gravedigging but since I stumbled across this in the course of my travels, there is a "clever" way to do what you describe–*at least in 2018, and at least since 2016*. You can retrieve an environment variable by key with [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html):

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --key YOUR_ENV_VAR_KEY
```

And likewise all environment variables with (as JSON or `--output YAML`)

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

Example usage in a container command:

```
container_commands:
    00_store_env_var_in_file_and_chmod:
        command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --key YOUR_ENV_KEY | install -D /dev/stdin /etc/somefile && chmod 640 /etc/somefile"
```

Example usage in a file:

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_do_stuff.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        YOUR_ENV_VAR=$(source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --key YOUR_ENV_VAR_KEY)
        echo "Hello $YOUR_ENV_VAR"
```

I was introduced to get-config by Thomas Reggi in https://serverfault.com/a/771067.

Comment: As of June 2020, Amazon Linux 2 platforms do not have `get-config`. A workaround that helped me is available here: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/issues/111#issuecomment-640949286

Comment: @penguinrob: Not true. We use `get-config` all the time with our Amazon Linux 2 environments. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html#custom-platforms-scripts.get-config). Thing is, you should use `.platform` [hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) instead of `.ebextensions`.

Answer (score 2):

*I assume that `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` are known to you prior to the app deployment.*

You can create the file on your workstation and submit it to Elastic Beanstalk instance with the code on `$ git aws.push`

```
$ cd .ebextensions
$ echo 'ABAC73E92DEEWEDS3FG4E:aiDSuhr8eg4fHHGEMes44zdkIJD0wkmd' > passwd-s3fs
```

In .config:

```
files:
    "/etc/passwd-s3fs" :
        mode: "000640"
        owner: root
        group: root

container_commands:
    10-copy-passwords-file:
        command: "cat .ebextensions/passwd-s3fs > /etc/passwd-s3fs"
```

You might have to play with the permissions or execute `cat` as `sudo`. Also, I put the file into .ebextensions for example, it can be anywhere in your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like your way of thinking! Creating more of an auto-deploy around Git might work for a lot of use cases. However `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` were mainly used as an example. I also have other variables I'd like to pass to my EC2 instance configuration script, like names of S3 buckets, IP-addresses, etc, that I'd like to configure on a per-instance basis...

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say "instance", do you mean "ec2 instance" or an instance of a particular environment, such as "dev", "qa" and so on? BTW, you did not mentioned "per-instance basis" requirement in your original question.

Comment: Sorry! I meant instance of a particular environment, as "dev", "qa" etc. I guess "Environment" would have been a clearer choice of wording in my previous comment. To clarify, taking the environment properties from the environment's software configuration, and using these in the `content:` declaration of the `files:` section of Elastic Beanstalk `.config` files.

Comment: So you have several environments for the same application. Each environment has a set of settings and you want to get those settings into configuration files. Same files, but different contents on each environment?

Comment: You sum it up quite nicely. It's easy to use these environment properties to configure my Java application by simply using the property values. However, I'd like to set up other software packages that I configure in my Elastic Beanstalk `.config` scripts in the same easy, per environment, manner (s3fs, FTP-server, etc). Granted this is doable through `container_commands:`, but if there's a clever way to do this in `files:`, that would save us developers a lot of work when we do more advanced configurations...